# Column name or number of supplied values does not match table definition

Tags: sql, coldfusion

i had a stored proc for which i made changes and added 2 new form fields to a stored proc 
and then ran it successfully 
now when i revoke the stored proc and run , it runs successfully but in the coldfusion
it gives the error

```
[Macromedia][SQLServer JDBC Driver][SQLServer]Insert Error: Column name or number of supplied values does not match table definition. 


90 :     <cfprocparam  type="in" cfsqltype="CF_SQL_INTEGER" dbvarname="@reportMonth"  value="#xxMDB#">
91 :     <cfprocparam  type="in" cfsqltype="CF_SQL_INTEGER" dbvarname="@orderBy"     value="#xxOBDB#">
92 :     **<cfprocresult name="xxResult">**
93 : </cfstoredproc>
```

Comment: I agree you should remove dbVarname and use positional notation.  

I know you said the procedure ran successfully, but the "Insert Error:..." looks like a direct database error.  Suggesting a problem within your procedure's sql. The dbvarname="@orderBy" also suggests your procedure might be using dynamic sql. Is it? 

Problems with dynamic sql are harder to debug and easy to miss. If your CF code values are different or in a different order than the ones used in your initial test, it might explain why the procedure seemed to work at first. (I am not a fan of dynamic sql)

Answer (score 1):

Since ColdFusion MX:

> Changed the dbvarname attribute
>   behavior: it is now ignored for all
>   drivers. ColdFusion uses JDBC 2.2 and
>   does not support named parameters.

http://www.cfquickdocs.com/cf8/#cfprocparam

Comment: @Henry: +1, and one virtual bonus point for cfquickdocs. :) Very nice, thanks.

Comment: @dan: That it used to work does not imply that it *still* works. Coldfusion 6 (aka MX) was quite a change to previous versions. They maintained compatibility quite well, but not everywhere. There is a "Code Analyzer" in the CF Administrator (under "Debugging & Logging") which can point out these kinds of things in your legacy code.

Comment: thanks henry for the link and thanks tomalak for the CFadmin path.
the error got corrected when the SQL server was rebooted once agian
today morning.
intact before that there was an undetected DB error too